# Getting error : 'admin' is not a registered namespace, on trying to access the password reset view

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I created a password reset view following [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html).

I used the urls for class based views since django uses CBVs in the version 2.1 and above. It seemed to work fine, but today I am getting the above stated error. I have commented the admin url, on uncommenting it the `password_reset` view works, but through the django registration and uses it's own template regardless of the templates I have created. Why am I getting this problem suddenly when it worked fine earlier?

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from NewApp import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import serve
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.user_login , name='user_login'),
    url(r'^NewApp/', include('NewApp.urls', namespace="NewApp")),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

NewApp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views   

app_name = 'NewApp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Apart from these, I have only used templates which are just copied from the link I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`views` for password reset need to access the admin by default. So you have to include the admin site to `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
]
```